# SSRS 2008 R2 - Can I reference a cell in the same row with an expression?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have a column with an expression returning a date (from a few different data points) that works fine, and in the next column I'm trying to return a numbered code (status code) depending on the dates that are returned. Can I do this with an expression?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... The "ReportItems!Whatevertextboxyouneedtoreference.Value" function seems to be doing the job.